# Connecting HTTPKit to a Theos application project. Undefined symbols error

Tags: objective-c, ios7, jailbreak, theos

### Aim

**I am trying to build the simplest Theos application that is acting like HTTP server.**

*I have no specific preferences on what libraries to use, but I tried by best using **[HTTPKit](https://github.com/fjolnir/HTTPKit)** this time. I will appreciate any comments and/or links on how to build such applications.*

### Question in a couple of words

Failed to use **[HTTPKit](https://github.com/fjolnir/HTTPKit)** in Theos application project. Getting "Undefined symbols" when using any of the HTTPKit classes.

### Personal thoughts

**I am sure the "Undefined symbols" error is caused by wrong linking. And I am almost sure that it has to do something with the [dependencies folder](https://github.com/fjolnir/HTTPKit/tree/master/dependencies) since I have no idea where to put it and how to link it.**

**It's not completely neccessary to use [HTTPKit](https://github.com/fjolnir/HTTPKit), but I am having quite the same troubles trying to implement [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) in Theos application.**

*I will also appreciate any comments on what I am doing wrong while installing Theos and making applications.*

### How I installed and configured Theos

1. Installed Theos using the **[following guide](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup)**
2. Downloaded everything from one of the **[headers repository](https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders)** into

   > $(THEOS)/include
3. Downloaded (additionally) IOSurfaceAPI.h from **[here](https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders/blob/master/_fallback/IOSurface/IOSurfaceAPI.h)** into

   > $(THEOS)/include/IOSurface

### Making a simple project

1.Created a Theos application using NIC

```
cd ~
$THEOS/bin/nic.pl
NIC 2.0 - New Instance Creator
------------------------------
  [1.] iphone/application
  [2.] iphone/library
  [3.] iphone/preference_bundle
  [4.] iphone/tool
  [5.] iphone/tweak
Choose a Template (required): 1
Project Name (required): name
Package Name [com.yourcompany.name]: 
Author/Maintainer Name [***]: 
Instantiating iphone/application in name/...
Done.
```

2.Put the whole repository **[HTTPKit](https://github.com/fjolnir/HTTPKit)** into newly created folder

> ~/name/HTTPSources

3.Added the following line

> name_FILES += $(foreach ext, c cpp m mm x xm xi xmi, $(wildcard
>   HTTPSources/*.$(ext)))

into the Makefile, so it looks like **[this](http://pastebin.com/V5Rgt8GY)**

4.Put all files from **[here](https://github.com/fjolnir/HTTPKit/tree/master/include/HTTPKit)** into newly created

> $THEOS/include/HTTPKit

5.Now the $(THEOS) folder looks like **[this](http://pastebin.com/iZvhTXax)**

6.***Calling make now doesnot cause fatal errors (except ldid command, which I guess is not vital) resulting in***

```
~/name/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk:41: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for application name...
 Copying resource directories into the application wrapper...
 Compiling main.m...
 Compiling nameApplication.mm...
 Compiling RootViewController.mm...
 Linking application name...
 Stripping name...
 Signing name...
/bin/sh: ldid: command not found
```

### Trying to use HTTPKit, getting errors

1.Added HTTPKit import and a few simple lines from the **[example](https://github.com/fjolnir/HTTPKit/blob/master/demo/main.m)**

```
HTTPServer * serv = [[HTTPServer alloc] init];
[serv handleGET:@"/hello/*"
           with:^(HTTPConnection *connection, NSString *name) {
               return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@!", name];
           }];
```

into ~/name/main.m so it looks like **[this](http://pastebin.com/RZpYd0Bp)**

2.Now calling make causes "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7" error

```
~/name/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk:41: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for application name...
 Copying resource directories into the application wrapper...
 Compiling main.m...
 Linking application name...
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HTTPServer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.m.f3071598.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [obj/name.app/name.ba964c90.unsigned] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-application-all_] Error 2
make: *** [name.all.application.variables] Error 2
```

### Additional info

**[find ~/name](http://pastebin.com/aFPtPcPb)**

**[make clean all messages=yes](http://pastebin.com/MGLX4aDP)**

Comment: Did you get this working? I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
     export ARCHS = armv7 arm64
     export TARGET = iphone:clang:7.0:7.0
```

to your **makefile**.

That fixed a similar error for me. If the error is different would you be so kind as to post the output?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Tried adding
export ARCHS = armv7 arm64
export TARGET = iphone:clang:7.1:7.1
Nothing changed, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing library. You only have HTTPServer header but lack of implement. Compile HTTPKit and put it on `$THEOS/lib`. Then add `name_LIBRARIES = nameoflibHTTKit` in `Makefile`